# I am creating a social media web app in .Net, what is the best approach for storing images/video?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, video

Should i store the images directly on the database as maybe a blob file or should i store them on the webserver, creating a folder for each user which will contain their images and store the path on a database table?.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting on Azure, then use **[Azure Blob](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#what-is)**

Otherwise, go with **[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)**

You can use your server to store them. Or you can even buy a separate server and use it as a CDN. But cloud storage services such as Azure Blob and Amazon S3 are more flexible. And Amazon is cheap.

**Stay away from storing media in database, whatever database. Or you will start seeing nightmare dreams soon after**

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response, It is just a plain webform application, i havent gone into hosting yet. so say for now if i just have a "Data" folder on the webserver (root directory of my application) where all images are just uploaded to will this be good enough approach?

Comment: i have no idea how large the data (images and other media files), but if they are considerably big enough, then consider cloud storage services per my answer. in case the data is small, then i think there is nothing wrong with putting the files in your web server.